# A Cryptic Way to Get There

Tags: cryptic-clues

> Good water hole (4)
>   Sheltered bay sanguine topped (7)
>   Sound pennies follow divorcee cost (7)
>   Cheering for Tiger Woods (3)
>   Roman one behind the levy cab (4)

Hopefully this one's decent and enjoyable. Feedback and recriminations welcome. There is also a final answer (12)

Comment: Homophones need to be indicated somehow - perhaps with "I hear" or "outspoken".

Comment: I should say if you were reading in the chat room, topped here is used differently.

Comment: @Deusovi, there are no homophones on this one my friend.

Comment: Wait, then what of Rand's answer to clue 3?

Comment: Pence follows ex. Right?

Comment: @John: Expen**s**e.

Comment: Ehhh... you're right when you're right. Good catch. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Final answer:

> WELL (ddef)
>  COVE+RED
>  EX+PENSE (hom)
>  FOR (hom?)
>  TAX+I
>
>  Well covered expense for taxi: **THOROUGH+FARE**

Comment: You're getting good at reading my mind. I'm going to have to give you credit for this one. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @John: I think you should give Rand the accept. He got most of the clues before me anyway, and his answers are more detailed. (And no problem - can't wait to see more cryptics from you! :D )

Comment: I think he'll live!!! But I'm kind of crediting you for helping me isolate problems. He did great.

Answer (score 7):

*Good water hole (4)*

> WELL ("good" ~ WELL, "water hole" = WELL)

*Sheltered bay sanguine topped (7)* - [solved by @tmpearce](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/42455/5373)

> COVERED ("sheltered bay" = COVE, "sanguine" = RED)

*Sound pennies follow divorcee cost (7)*

> EXPENSE ("pennies" = PENCE sounds like PENSE, "divorcee" = EX, "cost" = EXPENSE)

*Cheering for Tiger Woods (3)*

> Ugh, I know nothing about sport. But it's a three-letter word, so there aren't that many possibilities. My best guess would be FOR: there's a "for" in the clue, and something called [fore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fore_(golf)) in golf.

*Roman one behind the levy cab (4)*

> TAXI ("Roman one" = I, "levy" = TAX, "cab" = TAXI)

Putting it all together - [solved by @Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/42456/5373)

> *Well covered expense for taxi* - <s>perhaps the final answer should be TIP?</s> THOROUGHFARE ("well-covered" = THOROUGH, "expense for taxi" = FARE)

Comment: Yep. Good so far.

Comment: All correct. So a final then. Sounds like for, and everyone knows Tiger Woods.

Comment: "For" (or "fore") wouldn't be considered cheering though, would it?

Comment: @John What's the explanation of the Tiger Woods one supposed to be?

Comment: No good, cheering?

Comment: Yeah, I don't get the Tiger Woods one either. It's supposedly *not* a homophone, and it uses "FOR" in the clue itself which is generally not kosher in crossword clues in general.

Comment: @Deusovi, yeah, homophone. Pffff...

Comment: In golf, "Fore" would be a warning shout (usually by the golfer him/herself) to alert others of a wayward shot.  Not really a "cheer"

Comment: @John Is the final answer (putting it all together) right?

Comment: Alright, thank you for playing, still needed work! My apologies for that. Night!

Comment: @John: Hey, part of the goal of this site is to help people improve! My first cryptic clues were pretty bad - much worse than these!

Comment: Good job Rand...

Comment: @tmpearce, I was trying to be clever. Should definitely have put 'yelling' or 'shouting' instead.